# Javafx - Making a TableView Cell Change Style After Being Edited

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a TableView here that when a cell's value has been modified (the user can click a cell and type a new value) if the method isValid returns false, the cell gains the invalid-cell style from the stylesheet.

Currently, the editing part works fine and isValid returns what it is supposed to according to the console output. However, the cell is not gaining the invalid-cell attribute when isValid returns false.

I know the invalid-cell style is accessible, as having `column.getStyleClass().add("invalid-cell");` adds the style to the whole column, but I cannot make it so that it is just the modified cell that changes style at a time. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
public void loadTable(String tableName) throws SQLException {
        //Clear existing columns and entries
        tableView.getColumns().clear();
        tableView.getItems().clear();

        ObservableList<String> data = DBcontroller.getColumns(handler.getTable());


        //For each column, add to table
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            int finalIdx = i;
            TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<>(data.get(i));
            column.setPrefWidth(100); //Set width


            //Factory (gets column data)
            column.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
                String cellValue = param.getValue().get(finalIdx);
                return new SimpleStringProperty(cellValue);
            });


            //Make cells editable.
            column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter()));
            column.setEditable(true);

            column.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
                ObservableList<String> rowData = event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow());
                rowData.set(finalIdx, event.getNewValue());


                TableCell<ObservableList<String>, String> currentCell = event.getTableColumn().getCellFactory().call(column);
                if (isValid(event.getNewValue(), column.getText())) {
                    System.out.println("Input OK!");
                    currentCell.getStyleClass().remove("invalid-cell");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Input BAD");
                    currentCell.getStyleClass().add("invalid-cell");
                }
            });
            tableView.getColumns().add(column);
        }
```

Currently with the included code, none of the cells gain the style even when isValid returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I generally do in such cases is to put the logic in the `cellFactory`.

```java
        column.setCellFactory(x-> {
            TableCell<EventVW, Date> cell = new TableCell<EventVW, Date>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        ObservableList<String> styleClass = getStyleClass();
                        styleClass.remove("err-class"); 
                    } else {
                        setText(item);
                        styleClass.remove("err-class"); 
                        if(!isValid(item)) {
                            styleClass.add("err-class");    
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

So whenever the cell value is updated the style is updated too according to some function (`isValid`) in this example

Answer (score 0):

This is cleanest if done with PseudoClasses.  Also, whatever the validation routine is, it needs to be simple enough that it can be done in the "View" and not require database look-ups or complicated business logic.

```
public class ValidatingTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, String> {
    private static final PseudoClass redDisplay = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("error");

    public ValidatingTableCell() {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
        StackPane container = new StackPane(textField);
        container.getStyleClass().add("cell-box");
        container.setPadding(new Insets(8));
        itemProperty().addListener(itemProperty -> container.pseudoClassStateChanged(redDisplay, validateValue()));
        graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> !isEmpty() ? container : null, emptyProperty()));
        setText(null);
    }

    private boolean validateValue() {
        String theValue = itemProperty().get();
        return theValue == null || theValue.startsWith("A");
    }
}
```

And the CSS file looks like this:

```
.cell-box {
   -fx-background-color: green;
}

.cell-box:error {
  -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

This approach might look a bit odd, because it doesn't use the usual `updateItem()` approach, but instead binds to the `itemProperty()` in the `Cell`, and does all the connections in the `Cell` constructor which creates the layout.  The result is the same, though.

In this example, anything that has a value that starts with "A" will be considered invalid, and will get a red border around the `TextField`.  The validation is included as part of the `Cell` logic to make the point that it really needs to be simple to be included in the layout at all.

If the validation logic is more complicated, then the `Cell` data should be transformed into a `Object` containing fields for the data and the valid flag.  Then the linkage between the data itself and the valid flag should be defined in the business logic.

Comment: Cheers. Does using this approach have any benefit over the updateItem approach (ie, performance wise)?

Comment: @Hexadelta I prefer to view JavaFX as a Reactive framework.  So, static layouts that behave dynamically, bound to some data model that represents "State".  This approach fits that better, as you're not fiddling with any of the Nodes in the layout after the fact.  Note that there are no Nodes implemented as fields of the class, and none are referenced outside the layout constructor.  IMHO, it's a cleaner approach.  That being said, I have NEVER seen this presented in any documentation or on-line tutorial - for whatever that means.